# Show error on wordpress data Bases Connection Error

Tags: wordpress

my wordpress website unexpectedly down when traffic is increasing. it will automatically correct when there is no user browse the website. here is my site url:

http://himachal-news.com

Answer (score 0):

if your site is popular go for dedicated linux hosting, with enough memory. I think you currently you have shared hosting, that has shared and limited resources.

Comment: i am using ResellerClub hosting can you suggest me any best hosting

Comment: you can choose AWS or degital ocean  for this

Comment: these are best but a little expensive